# Android Game stuck on downloading resources on OnePlus 6 / OxygenOS 10.3.6

Tags: google-play-store, android-10, google-play-games, oxygenos, oneplus-6

Recently a game I have been following since day one got an update and my OnePlus seems to have a problem downloading the resources of the update.

Here is a screenshot of the game:
[image: screenshot of the stuck game]

As an aspiring developer myself I would like to know what causes such an issue and what the possible fixes are?

I'm from Bulgaria, tried 2.4G WiFi, 5G WiFi, mobile data, reinstalling, phone has more than 100GB free storage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it show an error in [tag:logcat]?

Comment: How can I access it and see?